# Inserting values in department table

Tags: mysql

getting following error while inserting values into table department

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Hr.Kadim,1234.43)' at line 2

```
INSERT INTO department (dept_name,building,budget)
    VALUES (Comp.Sci.,Hr.Kadim,1234.43);
```

Comment: You need some of these -> `'`

Comment: This is your second question so far when you ask basic SQL syntax questions. I recommend you find a book or tutorial or even look at the official documentation. Trying to guess is going to take really long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add single quotes with string values while inserting

```
INSERT INTO department (dept_name,building,budget) VALUES ('Comp.Sci.','Hr.Kadim',1234.43);
```